# Entity Framework: Bulk UpdateFromQuery in Batches

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-plus

I want to perform a bulk update for a Million+ rows.

However, I don't want to update the whole table, but rather in smaller batches (to prevent locking the whole table). Say every 10,000 rows.

Eg, similar to this answer: [How to update large table with millions of rows in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35903375/how-to-update-large-table-with-millions-of-rows-in-sql-server/35903495)

Currently using UpdateFromQuery to not load the whole context, and directly update the database.

Now how can I update in batches? Should I use the `.Take` Function?

```
var productUpdate = _dbContext.Set<Product>()
    .Where(x => x.ProductType == 'Electronics')
    .UpdateFromQuery( x => new Product { ProductBrand = "ABC Company" });
```

**Goal Code:**

[How to update large table with millions of rows in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35903375/how-to-update-large-table-with-millions-of-rows-in-sql-server/35903495)

```
SET @BatchSize = 10000;

SET @Rows = @BatchSize; -- initialize just to enter the loop

BEGIN TRY    
  WHILE (@Rows = @BatchSize)
  BEGIN
      UPDATE TOP (@BatchSize) prod
      SET Value = 'ABC Company'
      FROM dbo.Products prod
      WHERE prod.ProductType = 'Electronics'
   SET @Rows = @@ROWCOUNT;
 END;
```

Note: Currently refraining from using RawSql unless required

Comment: Take a look at this as well https://stackoverflow.com/a/44194925/2946329

Comment: hi @SalahAkbari yeah, we're aware of rawsql and fromsql, just want to see notes using EF Extensions and Update, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Entity Framework Plus](https://entityframework-plus.net/)

That is currently impossible to update using a `BatchSize`.

However, we will look at it and provide this feature.

I will update this answer once the feature is released.

---

**EDIT: Answer Update**

Since the v3.0.61, the `BatchSize` option is now supported for SQL Server.

You can now specify a `BatchSize` when using `UpdateFromQuery`

Comment: hi, do you know the estimate feature release date? 6-12 months? thanks for all your help !

Comment: cc @JonathonMagnan also, can you think of any workaround syntax? similar to question reference, thanks

Comment: @Artportraitdesign1, the delay will depends on my developer. He should try it this week, so if everything go well, a new version will be available next week, I cannot make any promise yet. There is currently no workaround syntax to get this desired behavior.